# Position of absolute element inside bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a full-width cover image. Inside of that, I have a bootstrap container class with an absolute positioned image that sits on top of the cover image. What I would like to to do is have that image positioned to the right-hand side of the container only.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="header-icon.png" class="header-icon" />
    </div>
</div>

#header {
  background-image: url('cover.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;

 .header-icon {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
 }
}
```

Of course, when I add right: 0 to the header-icon, it aligns outside the container. I could, of course, create media queries and try and position the icon based on screen size, but I'm wondering if a better way to do it exists.

I have also tried to make the icon relative to the container, but this seems to break what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Yorkford/mcsd4e03/), this is the code i added

```
#header .container {
 position: relative;
 height: 400px;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but it sounds like you want `right: 0` to align the image to the right of the `container` and not the `header`.

`position: absolute` will position an element absolutely according to the first parent element that is not positioned statically.  Right now, you have `#header` with relative position, but `.container` still has static position.  Therefore, you want to apply `position: relative` to the container:

```
#header .container {
  position: relative;
}
```

Also, the code you posted seems to be missing a `</div>`.